# Too few arguments in function to call [C program]

Tags: c, function, arguments

So, I have an assignment due tomorrow night for my online C programming class, and I am having some problems with my coding at the moment. I have brought the code to my teacher, but she doesn't seem to understand that she is being paid to teach me, not tell me that something is wrong with my code. I would appreciate if someone could take a look at the code and help me fix it. Code is located below. The location where I get my error is in main when calling the printtripSummary.

```
#include <stdio.h>


void welcomeMessage();
void askuserForInput();
void printtripSummary(float avgMiles, float minCost, float maxCost, float travelMiles);

int main()
{
    /* Call the functions */
    welcomeMessage();
    askuserForInput();
    printtripSummary();
    printf("\nThank you, please drive safely and have a nice trip!\n");
    return 0;
}


void welcomeMessage()
{
    printf("Welcome to the Trip Planner!\n");
    printf("So you are ready to take a trip? Let me help you plan for\n");
    printf("your fuels costs and required stops to fill up your tank.\n");
    printf("============================================================\n");
    printf("Please provide answers to the prompts below and I will\n");
    printf("display a summary for you when I have computed the results.\n");
    printf("============================================================\n");
}
void askuserForInput()
{
    float avgMiles, minCost, maxCost, travelMiles;
    do{
        printf("Please input your car's average miles per gallon (enter 0 to quit)>> ");
        scanf_s("%f", &avgMiles);
        if (avgMiles == 0)
            break;
        printf("Please tell me the range of fuel costs you expect to pay (per gallon>>)\n");

        printf("The lowest per gallon cost of fuel is>> ");
        scanf_s("%f", &minCost);
        printf("The highest per gallon cost of fuel is>> ");
        scanf_s("%f", &maxCost);
        printf("Please tell me how many miles you plan to travel>> ");
        scanf_s("%f", &travelMiles);
        printtripSummary(avgMiles, minCost, maxCost, travelMiles);
    } while (avgMiles != 0);
}

void printtripSummary(float avgMiles, float minCost, float maxCost, float travelMiles)
{
    float avgGal, mingasPrice, maxgasPrice;
    do{
        avgGal = travelMiles / avgMiles;
        mingasPrice = avgGal * minCost;
        maxgasPrice = avgGal * maxCost;
        printf("You will be required to purchase %.2f gallons of fuel.\n", avgGal);
        printf("The price will range between %2f and $%.2f.\n", mingasPrice, maxgasPrice);
    } while (avgMiles != 0);
}
```

Comment: And how, if I may ask, does this error make itself known?

Comment: Look at the prototype (and definition) for the `printtripSummary` function, then look at your call of that function.

Comment: In `main` where you call the function `printtripSummary` you have to give `parameters`! Also you call the function in `askuserForInput` so you have only to comment the function call in main out

Comment: @JoachimPileborg oh :-)

Comment: Well, the title you posted, i.e the compiler error it a perfectly fine diagnostics of what is wrong with your code. I suggest you read that error message again (instead of merely using it as a question title) and try to *understand* what it means. Then apply your new understanding to your code.

Comment: " she is being paid to teach me, not tell me that something is wrong with my code". Maybe she thinks the blindingly obvious error message is something you would learn more from addressing than if she just told you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out the function call in `main` like this (Line 13):

```
//printtripSummary();
```

Because you call the function already in `askuserForInput();` and this function get called in `main`

OR if you want to call the function also in main your have to pass the required arguments which are:

```
(float avgMiles, float minCost, float maxCost, float travelMiles)
```

Also you have a endless loop in the function `printtripSummary();` Because you have a `do...while` loop which checks if `avgMiles != 0`, but since your not changing the value of `avgMiles` in this loop it's endless!

Comment: Thank you so much. Commenting out the printtripSummary fixed it.

Comment: @Bioniclefreak25 Your welcome! Have a good day :D BTW look at the function `printtripSummary();` Because you have a endless loop there!

Answer (score 0):

On line 13 you're calling the `printtripSummary` function without passing any arguments to it. You have to provide the 4 arguments the function definition specifies (`avgMiles`, `minCost`, `maxCost`, `travelMiles`).